# How to segment a Specific Region of Interest (ROI) from Medical Kit Images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I need to extract a specific portion of an image for my project. The images I'm working with are medical kit images, and I have a sample image that shows the region of interest (ROI). The ROI is a rectangle in the middle of the image that includes the "C" and "T" parts. here the line beside the "C" refers the line as C line, same for the "T".

sample image:

[image]

the region that I want to segment is(the portion that is bounded by the yellow highlighter):

[image]

My code:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

# Define the ranges of hue values for the color red
lower_red1 = np.array([0, 70, 50])
upper_red1 = np.array([10, 255, 255])
lower_red2 = np.array([170, 70, 50])
upper_red2 = np.array([180, 255, 255])

def segmentation(img):
    # Convert the image to HSV color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Create the masks to select the red pixels
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red1, upper_red1)
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red2, upper_red2)
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
    # Apply morphological opening and closing to fill in gaps and remove small objects
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    # Apply the mask to the original image
    red_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    
    # Perform edge detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(red_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
    # Find the contours in the edge image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # Select the two contours that correspond to the two red lines
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:2]
    
    # Find the minimum bounding rectangle that contains both contours
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(np.concatenate(contours))
    # Crop the region of interest from the original image
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # Display the cropped ROI
    cv2_imshow(roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return roi
data = []
for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    path = os.path.join(data_dir, category)
    class_num = i

    for img in os.listdir(path):
        print(img)
        try:
            new_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
            new_array = segmentation(new_array)
            # new_array = cv2.resize(new_array, img_size)
            data.append([new_array, class_num])
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

this code segments some pictures crops correctly but most of the pictures are incorrectly cropped.

Comment: I'd use feature matching + homography, on the entire thing. then slice the interesting area out of there and analyze further.